# rearrange apps in launchers app drawer android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to make a launcher app I have made the app drawer and got apps with this code

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_drawer)
        view.adapter = getInstalledApps()?.let { AppDrawerAdapter(this, it) }
        view.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 5)
        view.hasFixedSize()
    }
    private fun getInstalledApps(): List<AppItem>? {
        val apps: MutableList<AppItem> = ArrayList()
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null)
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
        val untreatedAppList =
            applicationContext.packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)

        for (untreatedApp in untreatedAppList) {
            val appName =
                untreatedApp.activityInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString()
            val appPackageName = untreatedApp.activityInfo.packageName
            val appImage = untreatedApp.activityInfo.loadIcon(packageManager)
            val app = AppItem(appName, appImage, appPackageName)
            if (!apps.contains(app)) apps.add(app)
        }
        return apps
    }
```

the apps are displaying in a nonspecific order how to arrange them alphabetically

Answer (score 1):

Well, you simply sort the list.
Replace

```
return apps
```

with

```
return apps.sortedBy { it.appName }
```